# WinAPI RemoveDirectory - удаление директории до закрытия приложения

Tags: c++, winapi

После успешного удаления всех файлов деинсталлятор пытается удалить оставшиеся пустые директории. Алгоритм удаления - поиск путей директорий рекурсией c FindFirstFile/FindNextFile и запись их в вектор строк, после чего удаление директорий по путям с конца вектора с обработкой ошибок.
При отработке приложения картина следующая:
[image: Листинг работы деинсталлятора]

Получается, что удаляются только дочерние пустые директории, а как только цикл доходит до их родителя, отвечает ошибкой 145 (директория не пуста), хотя из листинга видно, что все потомки были удалены. А корневая директория вообще занята другим процессом (ошибка 32).
Повторюсь - все директории предварительно очищены от файлов.
Получается, что операция удаления директории является отложенной и удаление проходит после закрытия приложения. При повторном запуске деинсталлятора опять удаляются только последние пустые папки.
Использование в нужных местах CloseHandle и/или FlushFileBuffers результата не дало.
Вопрос в том, как заставить деинсталлятор удалять каталоги моментально, не дожидаясь закрытия приложения?

PS: деинсталлятор работает из другой независимой директории

Comment: `FindCloseFile` вызывается?

Comment: Нет конечно... сейчас попробую

Comment: Извините, `FindClose()`

Comment: Что-то не пойму где его вызвать. Вызываю при условии if(FileName != ".." && FileName != ".") перед рекурсией - удаляет не все файлы и всё равно встречается код 145

Comment: Вызывать нужно в конце цикла `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` на каждый безошибочный вызов `FindFirstFile` должен идти вызов `FindClose()`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё удаляется, правда кроме корневой папки.